# asp net mvc 4 application throws internal server error when add <serverRuntime> tag on xml web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I need to change maxRequestEntityAllowed default value using my web.config xml file
So I have added this to the xml:

```
<location path="gedaiapp">
   <system.webServer>
      <serverRuntime enabled="true" maxRequestEntityAllowed="524288000" />
   </system.webServer>
</location>
```

gedaiapp is my site configured on iis.
Doing that I am getting a internal server error when it tries to load some css files

Any idea on how to solve this? I have followed microsoft documentation:

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/serverruntime

Comment: Have you checked any error logs?  The Event Viewer on the box you're running this on might have some clues as to what the error is.

Comment: Do you mean the server the application is hosted or the client?

Comment: The server.  If you have access to the server you can check the Event Viewer which will usually log configuration file errors.  You could also log on to the server and then make a request to the site.  If the request is local ASP.NET should show you the exception message right in the browser.

Comment: thanks... I ll check that

Comment: http://postimage.org/image/fqe3mg1xl/ Here is what I am getting. Please, I have set override to true and know I could override in my web.config file. Yet not solved my problem. Found this: stackoverflow.com/questions/10122957/… My question is: This is an Asp Net mvc 4 application. Is there any other conf I should be paying attention at to check entities limits for upload?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem adding

```
<serverRuntime enabled="true" maxRequestEntityAllowed="524288000" />
```

directly to my applicationHost.config found at c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config

Comment: Just so you know this change is now true for all IIS hosted applications.  I would recommend only making this change at a site level.